# My JSON parsing fails

Tags: json, swift, alamofire

Im using SwiftyJSON, Alamofire_SwiftyJSON and Alamofire libraries. I'm trying to parse my response but it returns nothing("definitions" fails to print). 
JSON isn't empty it has got the response.

**So, my code looks like the following (nothing fails, it all compiles)**

```
 Alamofire.request(request).responseSwiftyJSON { dataResponse in

                if let JSON = dataResponse.result.value  {
                    print(JSON)

                if let definitions = JSON["results"]["lexicalEntries"]["entries"]["senses"]["definitions"].string {
                    print(definitions)
                    print("Hello")
                    }}
            }
```

**My response model looks like (this is not the whole response, that's just what I want to reach :**

```
{
  "results" : [
    {
      "language" : "en",
      "id" : "ace",
      "type" : "headword",
      "lexicalEntries" : [
        {
          "language" : "en",
          "entries" : [
            {
              "etymologies" : [
                "Middle English (denoting the ‘one’ on dice): via Old French from Latin as ‘unity, a unit’"
              ],
              "grammaticalFeatures" : [
                {
                  "type" : "Number",
                  "text" : "Singular"
                }
              ],
              "homographNumber" : "000",
              "senses" : [
                {
                  "definitions" : [
                    "a playing card with a single spot on it, ranked as the highest card in its suit in most card games"
```

**I think that my problem is in, should I add any parentheses or any symbols?**

```
if let definitions = JSON["results"]["lexicalEntries"]["entries"]["senses"]["definitions"].string
```

Comment: Several issues here attempting to access your JSON parsed object incorrectly. Firstly starting with no accessing array items properly. For example here `JSON["results"]["lexicalEntries"]`, the value `JSON["results"]` is an array so that's not a valid access. This happens more times as well further into your statement.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek Could you give me one correct step that goes further into my response please?

Comment: Try: `JSON["results"][0]["lexicalEntries"][0]` and so forth. Just make sure you are accessing based on the structure of your response. For some reason have nearly every object unnecessarily wrapped as an array.

Comment: Yes, it works, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are not indexing the corresponding arrays in your JSON response, to access the *definitions* array you can simply use

```
JSON['results'][0]['lexicalEntries'][0]['entries'][0]['senses'][0]['definitions']
```